# How to configure IP access in MongoDB atlas cluster though API or shell command?

Tags: mongodb, networking, nosql, mongodb-atlas

How to configure IP access in MongoDB atlas cluster though API or shell command ?

It's very time consuming to configure IP access to MongoDB atlas cluster though MongoDB GUI web platform each time.

It'd be very easy if we have some option to add IP to access MongoDB atlas cluster though some API or some Mongo shell command, so how to achieve that?

[image: mongodb atlas network access section]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API documentation - for managing the access list:  https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/api/access-lists/

Answer (score 2):

Here is current answer for CLI (to set up your current IP) - cli version is 1.7.3:

Docs: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/cli/stable/command/atlas-accessLists-create/

CLI call:

```
atlas accessList create --currentIp --type ipAddress --projectId $MONGO_ATLAS_PROJECT_ID --comment "Opening Network Access" --deleteAfter $EXPIRATON --output json
```

You need to provide only 2 parameters (except credentials of course):

```
MONGO_ATLAS_PROJECT_ID - ID of Your Mongo Atlas Project

EXPIRATON - Network Access expiration time in ISO-8601 format
```

This "--deleteAfter" parameter set by EXPIRATON var (considering You want your access to expire after some time) should be set in below format (based on linux date command):

```
date +%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z  ->  2023-09-23T08:14:16+0100
```

So when you want for it to expire after for example 15 minutes, it should be set like this:

```
EXPIRATION=$(date -d '+15minutes' +%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z)
```

Comment: can you give an example for the expiration value, I tried different things and I am getting this error `PERMANENT_ENTITY_CANNOT_BE_MADE_TEMPORARY`.

Comment: @YahiaNaguib If You run command mentioned by me above (date +%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z), then You'll get this: 2023-09-23T08:14:16+0100